# Uppload data from JSON to Sharepoint List with Microsoft Graph API in Python

Tags: python, flask, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

I am trying to add some data from a JSON file that has the same structure as a goal SharePoint list. I have previously checked that I can access the list with a get method and that I can authenticate and get the token. The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to properly do the data upload.

Below is my simplified code

```
URL= 'https://graph.microsoft.com/vx.x/sites/sharepointname/sites/group/lists/listId/rows/add'
json_file = a pandas file converted to json

post_data = requests.post( URL,
            headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token['access_token'], 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            data = json_file
            )
```

This does not work, some of the errors I got are "Resource not found for the segment \uxxxrows\uxxx."
I would be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might have gotten the URL wrong. That would explain the `Resource not found for the segment...` error you are encountering.

If you are trying to create a new list, [here's the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/list-create?view=graph-rest-1.0)
URL - `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists`

And if you are trying to add an item to an existing list, [here's the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-create?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
URL - `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items`

Comment: I have finally solved it. The URL indeed was wrong, the correct one was 
`URL='https://graph.microsoft.com/vxx/sites/sharepointsite:/sites/site:/lists/list id/items'`. Also, the way I was uploading the JSON was wrong. To generate a valid JSON I had to take each line individually from the panda dataframe, convert it to a proper format and then do a POST operation for each line in the following way:   
`requests.post(  
URL,
headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token['access_token'] , 'content-type': 'application/json'},
json=data,
)`
Kindly appreciate your help.